# Why I can't use vars() inside my function for a variable that is outside my function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables

I made a function named `translate(x)`. Outside this function, I made a variable named `korean`. I want to call my `korean` by using `vars()[]` function. But, instead of a successful compile, an error occured.

```py
korean = 'ko-KR'
lgf = 'korean'
def translate(x):
     lgfn = vars()[x]
     return lgfn;

translate(lgf)
```

I thought the output will be `'ko-KR'`, but after I compile it, it returns a `keyError: 'korean'`

Comment: Why are you doing this? There is no need to use `vars` here (there rarely is). In any case, you are passing **the string** `'korean'` into your function, and that is being used to key into the dictionary returned by `vars`. That isn't in the local variables, so you get the key error.

Comment: better use dictionary `language = { 'korean': 'ko-KR'}` and then you can do `return language[x]`. Using `vars()` is not prefered.

Comment: Function `vars()`, when called without parameters, is equivalent to `locals()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be using `globals` instead

```
korean = 'ko-KR'
lgf = 'korean'
def translate(x):
     lgfn = globals()[x]
     return lgfn;

print(translate(lgf))
```

ouput `ko-KR`

there are several ways to get environnement variables :

- globals() gives a dictionary of global variables
- locals() gives a
  dictionary of local variables

var() in your case will work as locals(), it will give you variables in your function scope. whereas globals holds all the global functions

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, there is no need `vars()` here. A simple dictionary will be enough

```
def translate(key):
    #Return value for a given key
    dct = {'korean': 'ko-KR'}
    return dct[key]

print(translate('korean'))
```

The output will be

```
ko-KR
```